# Record/Save Video Using GPUImage in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, gpuimage

I'm using a "Record" button that users can hold down to record their video. When the user stops holding down the "Record" button, I'd like to save the video they recorded to the photos album. I'm a bit stuck with the UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum function. My code so far:

```
    @IBAction func RecordAction(sender: UIButton) {
    // User is holding down record button 
    if (!isRecording) {
        do {
            self.isRecording = true
            let documentsDir = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain:.UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL:nil, create:true)
            let fileURL = NSURL(string:"test.mp4", relativeToURL:documentsDir)!
            do {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(fileURL)
            } catch {
            }
            movieOutput = try MovieOutput(URL:fileURL, size:Size(width:400, height:645), liveVideo:true)
            camera.audioEncodingTarget = movieOutput
            filter --> movieOutput!
            movieOutput!.startRecording()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't initialize movie, error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func RecordDone(sender: UIButton) {
    // After user stops holding down the button, save video to gallery
    if isRecording == true {
        movieOutput?.finishRecording {
            self.isRecording = false
            self.camera.audioEncodingTarget = nil
            self.movieOutput = nil
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathToMovie, nil, nil, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this for saving the video:

```
func StartWritingvideo()
{
    player.pause()

    filters.removeAllObjects()

    var paths: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

    let  filePath : String!

    if trim == true
    {
        filePath = paths[0].stringByAppendingString("/output/outPut.mov")
    }
    else
    {
        filePath = paths[0].stringByAppendingString("/image.mov")
    }
    self.movieFile = GPUImageMovie(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    self.movieFile.runBenchmark = true
    self.movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = false
    filters = [GPUImageAmatorkaFilter(),GPUImageMissEtikateFilter(),GPUImageSoftEleganceFilter(),FIIIN()]

    let indexpaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
    let indexpath = indexpaths[0] as NSIndexPath


    self.movieFile.addTarget(self.filters[indexpath.row] as! GPUImageInput)
    let pathToMovie = paths[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("IMG_filtered.MOV")
    do
    {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(pathToMovie)
    }
    catch
    {
        error as NSError
    }
    let Data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    print( Data?.length )
    let anAsset = AVAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))

    let videoAssetTrack = anAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    var naturalSize = CGSize()

    print(naturalSize)
    naturalSize = videoAssetTrack.naturalSize
    self.movieWriter = GPUImageMovieWriter(movieURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie), size: naturalSize)
    let input = self.filters[indexpath.row] as! GPUImageOutput
    input.addTarget(self.movieWriter)
    self.movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = true
    if anAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio).count > 0 {
        self.movieFile.audioEncodingTarget =  self.movieWriter
    }
    else
    {
        self.movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = nil
    }

    self.movieFile.enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter(self.movieWriter)
    self.movieWriter.startRecording()
    self.movieFile.startProcessing()
    self.movieWriter.completionBlock =

    {() -> Void in

        self.stop = false
        self.movieWriter.finishRecording()
        self.movieFile.cancelProcessing()
        input.removeAllTargets()
        self.movieFile.removeAllTargets()


        if self.isLive == false
        {
            ALAssetsLibrary().writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathToMovie), completionBlock:
            {_ in

                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
                self.player.pause()
            })
        }else {


                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

        }

    }


}
```

I have nice knowledge for GPUImageFilter If you want any help ask me. Please give up mark if you find my answer helpful.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Where exactly should this code go? Under the "IBAction func RecordDone(sender: UIButton)" part?

Comment: it's code for writing the video to your document directory.. When you input single-simple video into that it will convert and save it to document directory.

Comment: Hi @JAck .. Can you please help me with GPUImageFilter? I'm facing an issue with video filters and I'm totally stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @JAck can you help me how to save filter video in photos, because this GPUImageMovieWriter class not available in GPUImage2 for swift.